# OpenCV video slow on windows with QtCreator

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator, video-capture

I'm trying to create an application that lets you load up images in an order, like slides in a presentation program, and when you launch it it shows the first image, along with what your camera sees. The camera records and checks for signs of a red object, namely a laser, and then it changes slides, depending on the location it found the laser on, top half means next slide, bottom half means previous.

The problem is that the video is very slow on windows, as opposed to on linux where it runs smoothly with the same exact code. I'm using OpenCV and QtCreator for the application.

This is the code for the recording function:

```
void slideshow()
{
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    int incr = 30, slide = 0, numb;
    bool loop = true, found = false, menjai = false, left;
    cv::Mat frame;
    std::string path = SlideList[0];
    numb = int(SlideList.size());
    while(loop) {
        if (menjai) {
            if (!left){
                slide++;
                if (slide > numb-1)
                    slide = 0;
            }
            else {
                slide--;
                if (slide == -1)
                    slide = numb-1;
            }
            path = SlideList[slide];
            menjai = false;
        }
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread(path);
        cv::namedWindow("slajd", cv::WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN);
        cv::imshow("slajd",img);
        cap >> frame;
        cv::rectangle(frame, cv::Point(40, 10), cv::Point(600, 220), cv::Scalar(255,55,0), 1, 8, 0);
        cv::rectangle(frame, cv::Point(40, 260), cv::Point(600, 480), cv::Scalar(255,55,0), 1, 8, 0);
        if (found)
            incr--;
        if (incr == 0) {
            incr = 30;
            found = false;
        }
        int x = 40;
        while (x < 600 && !found) {
            int y = 10;
            while (y < 480 && !found) {
                if (y == 220)
                    y = 260;
                cv::Vec3b pixel = frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(x,y));
                if (pixel[2] > 200) {
                    cv::circle(frame, cv::Point(x,y), 10, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
                    menjai = !menjai;
                    found = true;
                    if (y <= 220)
                        left = false;
                    else
                        left = true;
                }
                y += 5;
            }
            x += 5;
        }
        cv::imshow("ses",frame);
        if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
}
```

Even if I comment out the whole looking for laser part, it's still slow.
Why is the program slow on windows while it runs smoothly on linux and if I can, how can I fix this?

Also, I'm really not sure about which version I'm using, I downloaded OpenCV 3.1.0 but the include is opencv2.